# Multi-level data sources using entity framework

Tags: gridview, entity-framework-5, datasource, entitydatasource

I am trying to use EF to build a devexpress gridview that as multi-level display. I use the Data Sources in VS 2013 following the following steps:

- Add New Data Source
- Data Source Type: Object
- Data Bind to: SP_User

Here is my DB tables

[image: DB Tables]

Now the problem comes in that the data source only goes up to the second level of the data source and I need to be able to access the third level but there is no option to make it as a datagrid.

[image]

How do I get the third and fourth level as gridviews?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Navigation Properties between tables ? 
and check Entities.vb ..

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by that but if you mean associations then yes they are all there.

Comment: or other ideea ! why you don't create a dataSet to use like DataSource for DGVs, with all Tables as DataTable, linked by PRIMARY Key, and this must work ..